# Read all the variables and fact and set them as linux environment variables

Tags: ansible

[Solved] this problem is solved. I will post the solution later. Thank you

I have variables such as these:

```
mycompany_package1_key1: ...
mycompany_package1_key2: ...
mycompany_package2_key1: ...
mycompany_package2_key2: ...
mycompany_package3_key1: ...
```

The good thing thing is they are visible in playbooks. I can refer to them directly like this: `{{ mycompany_package1_key1 }}`.

The problem is that these keys are not available in the tests because I am not running them as part of ansible. To overcome this problem, I want to run a playbook that would set them as linux environment variables before running my tests. Then I will be able to read those environment variables in Ruby.

If I am able to read them, then I think I will be able to write some logic in the playbook itself that will set environment variables only if a variable starts with `mycompany_`.

I am stuck on the reading part itself:

```
- name: Read All Ansible variables.
  debug:
    var=hostvars[item]
  loop: "{{ hostvars }}"
```

I have also tried this:

```
- name: "Ansible | List all known variables and facts"
    debug:
      var: hostvars[inventory_hostname]
```

hostvars or hostvars[ inventory_hostname] is bundling everything together instead of giving me seperate key/values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I did it in three steps like this:

- name: Read all the variables
  debug:
  var: hostvars[inventory_hostname]
  register: myallthevariables

```
- name: Store them in a text file
  with_dict "{{ myallthevariables['hostvars[inventory_hostname]'] }}"
  shell: "printf {{ item.key }}={{ item.value}}'\n' >> /path/to/file.txt"
```

Third step is to read the text file in my test and store the values in a Map (Hashes in Ruby) and then proceed or set them up as Linux ENV variables.

I can't do it thru ansible because ENV variables are applicable to the child process where those ENV variables are set and since my tests run in a different process, it didn't workout for me.